# RUTA how to execute a block depending on a condition

Tags: java, uima, ruta

I have a simple Ruta question.

In the example taken from the tools.ruta.book.pdf

Paragraph{IF(keywordAmount > 5)->MARK(KeywordParagraph)};

is it possible, instead of executing just one statement, to execute either a block that has been defined before or a function?

Comment: Just that I understand your question correctly: the executing statement refers to the action, the creation of an annotation, and you want to execute several actions, blocks or functions if the rule is able to match successfully?

Comment: What I want to do is instead of calling MARK to write something like:  Paragraph { IF(kewordAmount>5) -> execute_block_x ) }; Does Ruta support this syntax?

Answer (score 1):

UIMA Ruta provides various actions for different tasks. The actions CALL and EXEC are able to apply scripts, blocks and analysis engines.

The CALL action is typically used when additional rules should be applied in case the rule matches. The argument of the action points either to an additional script file, or to a script file (which can be the same one) followed by block names (with dots). You can therefore define different blocks in an external script file, which are called separately by the main script file. The examples in the documentation mention most of the time something like `Document{->CALL(AnotherScript)};`, but this is also only a normal rule. The action can be used in any kind of rules at rule elements with any kind of conditions.

For the example you mentioned in your question, maybe something like the following is interesting for you:

Paragraph{IF(kewordAmount>5) -> CALL(MyScript.BlockX))};

Mind that BlockX is executed for each match of the rule element (for each paragraph that fulfills the condition), and only within the context of the matched span of the rule element (only within these paragraphs).

The EXEC action is typically used when applying additional analysis engine since the CALL action is sensible to the filtering settings.

If additional functionality needs to be executed in case a rule matches, then either an additional action can be added to the language, which provides the functionality, or an external analysis engine is implemented that solves the task.